# Integral of function involving Dirac delta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, integral-transforms

I am performing lots of simple calculations with dirac delta functions. It would be awesome if *Mathematica* could do this routine exercise for me, eliminating any possible human errors. For example, this integral:

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[t - a - (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2)] /
  (4 Pi (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2)), {a, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

*Mathematica* does not know how to evaluate it.

I tried using `FunctionalExpand` to expand the delta-function, but in this case it does nothing. But I can easily take the integral above manually.

Maybe there is a way of evaluating such integrals automatically?

Comment: This integral makes no sense in traditional math (see [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Generalized_function) and references  there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding assumptions finds two of the cases.

```
Assuming[{a, t, r, z} ∈ Reals && t > z,
 Integrate[
  DiracDelta[
    t - a - (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2)]/(4 Pi (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2)),
  {a, -Infinity, Infinity}]
 ]
(*  1/(4 π t - 4 π z)  *)

Assuming[{a, t, r, z} ∈ Reals && t < z,
 Integrate[
  DiracDelta[
    t - a - (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2)]/(4 Pi (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2)),
  {a, -Infinity, Infinity}]
 ]
(*  (-t + z)/(4 π r^2)  *)
```

The case `t == z` seems to reveal a bug:

```
Assuming[{a, r, z} ∈ Reals,
 Integrate[
  DiracDelta[
     t - a - (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2)]/(4 Pi (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2)) /. t -> z,
  {a, -Infinity, Infinity}]
 ]
```

> Select::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in `` Select[Integrate`ImproperDump`newx,Integrate`NLtheoremDump`sel$293548] ``. >>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: At `t==z`, the argument of `DiracDelta` vanishes only at `Infinity`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, however, the interesting thing to me (with respect to this site) was that the internal code committed a programming error.

Answer (score 4):

Although Mathematica cannot solve

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[g[x]] h[x], x]
```

as written, it can be transformed to

```
Integrate[DiracDelta[x-x0] h[x] / (Abs[D[g, x]]/.x -> x0), x]
```

using [standard formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function), where `g[x0] == 0`.  (Note that, if `g[x]` has multiple real zeroes, the preceding expression must be summed over those zeroes.)

This can be applied to the specific case here as follows, with `q` the original integral:

```
arg = Cases[q, DiracDelta[z_] -> z, Infinity];
a0 = a /. First@Solve[arg == 0, a];
q /. DiracDelta[z_] :> DiracDelta[a - a0]/(Abs[D[arg, a] /. a -> a0])

(* {Boole[-Infinity < -((r^2 - t^2 + z^2)/(2*t - 2*z)) < Infinity]/
     (2*Pi*Sqrt[(r^2 + (t - z)^2)^2/(t - z)^2]*
     Abs[1 + (-r^2 + (t - z)^2)/(Sqrt[(r^2 + (t - z)^2)^2/(t - z)^2]*(t - z))])} *)
```

If the constants contained in the argument of `Boole` are real, it evaluates to `1`, and the expression greatly simplifies.

```
Assuming[{a, t, r, z} \[Element] Reals, Simplify[%]]
(* Piecewise[{{(4*Pi*t - 4*Pi*z)^(-1), t >= z}}, (-t + z)/(4*Pi*r^2)] *)
```

(This is, of course, the approach used by Alexei Boulbitch in his earlier answer.)

Comment: I think there's something missing from your code -- `q` at least -- but I can't reproduce your answer.  I guess I'm brain-dead or something.  If you `Simplify` your answer with assumptions that the variables are real, it comes out nice.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Sorry, `q` is the original integral.  I have updated my answer (and also rerun the code to assure that it works).  Thanks for pointing out the omission.

Comment: +1 It works now.  Note also if I use `q = Inactivate[<integral>, Integrate]` and then `Activate` on the last line, I save myself about 6 seconds on the first, fruitless attempt at the integral.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Thanks for the `Inactivate` suggestion.  By the way, I simplified my final result by assuming all constants are real, as you did.

Comment: My question was whether this could be done automatically or not.

Comment: @Hindsight  My approach does provide an answer automatically in the sense that you just name your integral `q` and then apply the code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    1/(4 Pi (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2)) /. (Solve[
     t - a - (r^2 + (z - a)^2)^(1/2) == 0, a][[1, 1]]) // Simplify

(*  1/(2 \[Pi] Sqrt[(r^2 + (t - z)^2)^2/(t - z)^2])  *)
```

Have fun!